# AddToHook for polyglossia to change chapter name doesn't work

Tags: polyglossia, hooks

I want to change the `chaptername` from `פרק` (polyglossia's default) to `חלק`.

Because the `.tex` file is created with LyX, and since the LyX editor adds the `\usepackage{polyglossia} \setdefaultlanguage{}` commands at the end of the preamble, I need to use a hook to patch this command to the end of the preamble.

I tried the following but it doesn't make any change, and I would like to know why.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]

\AddToHook{package/polyglossia/after}{%
  \gappto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand\chaptername{חלק}}
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\gappto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand\chaptername{חלק}} %<- Actually works

\begin{document}

\chapter{הקדמה}
לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט
\end{document}
```

[image: output pdf]

Comment: well the language is loaded after polyglossia and so after your hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the hook does nothing, because at the time the code is executed, `gloss-hebrew.ldf` has not yet been loaded.

Thus `\gappto` just defines `\captionshebrew` to do that `\renewcommand`, but when `gloss-hebrew.ldf` is loaded this is superseded by

```
\def\captionshebrew{...}
```

The correct way is to `\gappto` *after* loading the language.

If you add `\show\captionshebrew` after `\usepackage{polyglossia}` but before `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`, you get on the console

```
> \captionshebrew=macro:
->\renewcommand \chaptername {חלק}.
```

If you also add `\show\captionshebrew` after `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`, you see

```
> \captionshebrew=macro:
->\def \prefacename {מבוא}\def \refname {מקורות}\def \abstractname {תקציר}\def
\bibname {ביבליוגרפיה}\def \chaptername {פרק}\def \appendixname {נספח}\def \con
tentsname {תוכן העניינים}\def \listfigurename {רשימת האיורים}\def \listtablenam
e {רשימת הטבלאות}\def \indexname {מפתח}\def \figurename {איור}\def \tablename {
טבלה}\def \partname {חלק}\def \enclname {רצ"ב}\def \ccname {העתקים}\def \headto
name {אל}\def \pagename {עמוד}\def \psname {נ.ב.}\def \seename {ראה}\def \alson
ame {ראה גם}\def \proofname {הוכחה} \def \glossaryname {מילון מונחים}.
```

You might use `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]

\AtBeginDocument{\gappto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand\chaptername{חלק}}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\chapter{הקדמה}
לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @tush `\AtBeginDocument{\gappto\captionshebrew{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{חלק}}}` Comment: LyX is supposed to make things easier, isn't it? Well, my opinion on it is known: trash it.